# Snowflake and Data Factory Error because of regions

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, blobstorage

Im getting an error when running Data Factory to load data into Snowflake:

```
ErrorCode=SnowflakeUnsupportedCouldPlatformForImport,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Snowflake only support the account hosted in azure platform while as sink connector, please make sure your account is hosted in azure, current region and platform is '',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
```

Does the azure blob storage (staging area for copy command) needs to be in the same region as where snowflake was provision?

Comment: The error you are getting is not a Snowflake one, it comes from ADF and seems that current region and platform are not detected well, as your error message says **current region and platform is ''** while it should populate the '' with a value. I would recommend to reach out to Microsoft.

Comment: When you do the initial setup of Snowflake, do you need to allow the principal to have access to the subscription?  Last time I did a setup (2 years ago), I remember something like that.  Just making sure.

Comment: If you are referring to this [step](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-config.html#step-2-grant-snowflake-access-to-the-storage-locations) then yes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case going to the warehouse you have configured and enabling **"Auto Resume"** solved the issue for me. Hope this helps someone running into this same issue.

[image]